Power BI Slicer options settings
In Power BI, I have three slicers: Slicer 1, Slicer 2, and Slicer 3. Slicer 1 acts as the primary slicer, with two options labeled "program" and "non-program." Meanwhile, Slicer 2 and Slicer 3 each contain five options (A, B, C, D, and E). When I select an option in Slicer 1, it filters the available options in Slicer 2 and Slicer 3 accordingly. However, I want to ensure that the filtering starts with Slicer 1 as the primary filter.
Currently, if I choose options A or B in Slicer 2 or Slicer 3 first, it can cause the "non-program" option in Slicer 1 to disappear, even though it's not applicable for the selection. Instead of having it disappear, I would like the "non-program" checkbox to remain visible but remain unchecked, indicating that it is not applicable for the current selection. This would ensure that Slicer 1 maintains its full list of options for the user, even when the filters in Slicer 2 and Slicer 3 are applied first. The goal is to improve the filtering experience by retaining the visibility of all options in Slicer 1 while still indicating which are relevant.
Is there any possibility to do this power BI?

You want to prevent Slicer 2 and Slicer 3 from filtering out options in Slicer 1. Instead, you want Slicer 1 to always display both "program" and "non-program" options. To do this:
Go to "Edit Interactions", click on any of your visuals (e.g., your slicers). You'll see an "Edit Interactions" option under the "Format" tab in the ribbon.
Select Slicer 2 and Slicer 3 one by one, and ensure that they do not cross-filter Slicer 1. You can do this by selecting the "None" interaction for Slicer 1 when editing slicer interactions.
You can add further to it by making a flag type measure  to indicate whether a value should be greyed out in slicer 1 and then add it as a conditional formatting for the slicer one. It will grey out the option which is not applicable or has been filtered out in a particular situation.
